# How to enable mediacodec encoding using ffmpeg?

Tags: c, android-ffmpeg

From the ffmpeg docs, it looks like hw accel media encoding using mediacodec is supported from version 6.0. How do I use it?
I compiled the library with media_codec_enabled and enable-jni flags and I do see h264_mediacodec as one of the encoders.
Will the media codec encoders be used automatically or do I have to do something?

Doing avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_mediacodec") gives the codec id as H264.

Presently, I am calling avformat_alloc_output_context2() and adding the h264 video encoding to AVFormatContext which then added to av_interleaved_write_frame().

Example on how to encode using h264_mediacodec

Comment: Have you checked their encoding example? Maybe it can help. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c